# Why is guest OS greyed out in vmware web client?

Tags: virtual-machine

I want to open the console for the guest OS on a VM in Vsphere using Firefox on OSX. Everything is working properly on the machine. I am able to console using the desktop client program in windows -- but when I go to try to open the console in web client on OS X, the "Open console" button is greyed out. [image] What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you click the Summary Tab in the secondary pane there should be a Console plug-in that can be installed, worked on Windows 8 for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the maintenance mode, some features will be disabled. Exit maintenance mode to re-enable them.

[image]